# How to retrieve unchanged value on OPC UA Subscribe

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I want to retrieve data per Publishing Interval, even data changed or not. As I read OPC documentation, I can only get DateChangeFilter to retrieve the values on OnChange.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If creating your item with a `DataChangeTrigger` of `StatusValueTimestamp` doesn't get you all the changes you want there is nothing you can do.

Alternatives would be periodically calling the Read service instead of using a MonitoredItem or maybe calling the ResendData method every time you want to force the subscription to send the last value for all its items.